# Writing csv or xslx file to disc from shiny web application

Tags: r, file, shiny

i have a shiny web-application, where I'm making an upload form like such

UI component:

```
  fileInput(
  'file1', 'Choose file to upload',
   accept = c(
     'text/csv',
     'text/xlsx',
     '.csv',
     '.xlsx'
     )),   
  mainPanel(
  tableOutput("contents")
  )
  ))
```

Server component:

```
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    #Check if file is null
    if(is.null(inFile)){
      return(NULL)
    } 

    #Check if file extension is .xlsx 
    if(grepl(".xlsx", inFile$name)){
    write.xlsx(inFile$datapath, file="testexcelfile",
               sheetName="Test file", append=FALSE)
    data <- read.xlsx(inFile$datapath)
    return(data)

    #or if file extension is .csv
    }else if(grepl(".csv", inFile$name)){
      write.csv2(inFile, file="TestCsv.csv")
      data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
      return(data)
    }
    else{
      return("Please enter a file with format .xlsx or .csv")
    }
  })
})
```

the problem is that, the content is not written correctly to fthe file, instead the attributes of the ile (which is type list) is written in like this (see picture),

is anybody familiar, of how i can write the raw contents of the file instead of the attributes?

[image: <code>\[!\[CSV output\]\[1\]\]\[1\]</code>]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the temporary file path. You can use `file.copy()` to copy file from that temporary path to your destination.

Note that if you deploy your app on shinyapps.io, you won't be able to write file to local storage permanently.

Comment: If i want to save The file on The server, is it possible to use this method (by renaming The file on The server)

Comment: Yes. You can save the file on server as long as you're not using shinyapps.io.